# Empty sitemap error in search console after moving to https with Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, https, sitemap, google-search-console

I'm on Wordpress 4.8.1, with Yoast SEO sitemap.xml enabled. I recently moved to https.

After submitting the sitemap to search console it says the sitemap is empty and does not contain URLs. But I can see content of the page in browsers and google bots can crawl it too.

I submitted to search console http, https, www and non www domains. And I get this problem on all the versions. When it was just http I had no problems with the sitemap.

I 301'ed sitemap_index.xml to sitemap.xml

My robot.txt:

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /

Sitemap: https://giessedati.it/sitemap.xml
```

I used some validator and all say the sitemap is valid.
I tried uninstalling-reinstalling Yoast Seo and other sitemaps plugins with no results.
I removed caching plugin (W3 Total cache) and cached content of the site.

Comment: try to put sitemap.xml manually.

Comment: Through FTP? If the .xml file is called differently than sitemap.xml or sitemap_index.xml, it does work. But this is not a solution since the sitemap needs to auto-update.

Comment: first check with manual update. If its work then plugin sitemap also will work.

Comment: What do you mean with manual update? can you explain?

Comment: create manually sitemap.xml and upload Through FTP

Comment: Manual doesn't work if I call it sitemap.xml, only if I use a different name.

Comment: name does not matter, I think you have any other problem, Check permission for that file and also check any other condition block the sitemap

Comment: There are no errors that I can see.